# PHP Sessions declaring 'Chinese' from the array

Tags: php, if-statement

When i print_r my session i get:

```
Array ( [languages] => Array ( [0] => Chinese ) )
```

which is what i wanted.

And I have an if statement which is:

```
if($SESSION == 'Chinese'){
        $_POST['languages'] = array('Chinese');

}
```

Which i think is 100% correct, but the problem I have is getting the if statement to compare to the correct part of the array. The If statement doesnt work though. I thought it maybe something like :

`$session[0]` but that doesnt work, could it im using the wrong parameter should i be using something other then `==`, and ideas would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if($SESSION["languages"][0] == 'Chinese'){
        $_POST['languages'][] = "Chinese";

}
```

You can also do this...

```
$_POST['languages'] = $SESSION["languages"];
```

What you want is...

```
$languages = array("English","Japanese","Chinese","Hungarian","Arabic","French","Russian","Korean","German");
foreach($_SESSION["languages"] as $language){
    if(in_array($language, $languages)){
        $_POST["languages"][] = $language;  
    }
}
```

Comment: didnt work. Still says the same print message, but doesnt work.

Comment: Ok, what is the point of your IF condition? Make a new array with languages is $_POST array?

Comment: Is there only Chinese or more languages?

Comment: Many more languages, "English","Japanese","Chinese","Hungarian","Arabic","French","Russian","Korean","German"

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps:

```
if ($_SESSION['languages'][0] == 'Chinese') {
    $_POST['languages'] = array('Chinese');
}
```

Comment: This was correct however, the second line had to remain as it was in my example above. Thankyou

Comment: @Ryan: Fixed to match your example.

Answer (score 0):

You want:

```
if($_SESSION['languages'] == 'Chinese')
```

However what you don't want to do is assign values to the $_POST array. These values should only be populated from the client side(submitting form etc).

Comment: thanks, a few people have said that to me, but i dont understand what you mean by you need to assign it to the post array.

Comment: I'm claiming you do not want to assign values to the $_POST array via PHP.